# How to index match with conditions in sql

Tags: sql

I have tables like this:

`regist` table

| userID | registDate |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-22 |
| 2 | 2022-01-23 |

`session` table

| userID | date_key | traffic |
| --- | --- | --- |
| null | 2022-01-02 | facebook |
| 1 | 2021-01-03 | facebook |
| 1 | 2021-01-04 | google |
| 1 | 2021-01-05 | linkedin |
| 2 | 2021-01-15 | facebook |
| 2 | 2021-01-25 | facebook |
| 3 | 2021-01-20 | facebook |

Output

| userID | date_key | traffic | regist date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-03 | facebook | 2022-01-22 |
| 1 | 2021-01-04 | google | 2022-01-22 |
| 1 | 2021-01-05 | linkedin | 2022-01-22 |
| 2 | 2021-01-15 | facebook | 2022-01-23 |

How do I merge the tables so that I can return the regist date. Do I do a right join?

Is this correct?

```
select * 
from sessiontables st 
left join registtable rt on st.userID = rt.userID
where st.userID is not null
```

How to do exist userID exist in regist table statement?

Comment: What's your dbms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understand correctly, You can try to use self join with an aggregate function.

```
select rt.userID,
       st.date_key,
       st.traffic,
       rt.registDate
from (
    SELECT userID,min(date_key) date_key,traffic
    FROM sessiontables
    GROUP BY traffic,userID
) st
JOIN registtable rt 
ON st.userID=rt.userID
```

Comment: Great! This answer would be useful. Its working like charm.